# vb.net check if process I started is done

Tags: vb.net

I have started a process:

```
Dim getUdpate as Process
getUpdate = New Process
getUpdate.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\UTIL\GETBTCH.BAT"
getUpdate.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
getUpdate.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
getUpdate.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\UTIL\"
getUpdate.Start()
getUpdate.Close()
```

Then, I want to Run another process but I want to check first if the `getUpdate` process is already finished.

How do I check if the process is already finished?

I already tried to look at the processes ID, but it only display cmd.exe and there are a lot of cmd.exe as the processes ID so I can't just go and stop all of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the [HasExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) property of the process.  It will return true if the process has ended, and false if it is still running.

You will need to check this before you call `Close()` on your `getUpdate` Process object.  So `getProcess` will have to remain open until the procsses has exited.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`getUpdate.WaitForExit();` instead of

`getUpdate.Close()`

Comment: when I use WaitForExit, my application somehow, pauses, like listbox not updating and will only return to normal after WaitForexit. I am looking for an alternative if I could check the process i created if it is still running or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a WinForms application or similarly interactive UI I suggest hooking a function into the object's [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event instead of polling `HasExited`.

(You may already know this but) if you use `WaitForExit` or poll `HasExited` your UI is hanging exactly because your code is actually waiting for the process to end.

Your UI only has one thread and cannot "multitask". That's why these "processing" type of actions should be done in a different thread (or, as is the case here, a different process) and report back to the UI when they finish.

Example:

```
' Handle Exited event and display process information.
Private Sub myProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Do something in your UI
End Sub
```

and in your starting code:

```
getUpdate.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler getUpdate.Exited, AddressOf myProcess_Exited
```